# Declaring an async method that can be both awaited *and* run asynchrously without waiting for it to finish?

Tags: c#, async-await

Let's say you're developing an api and want to offer async methods but there's a possibility that the user doesn't actually want to 'await' for a particular async method to finish before continuing to the next line; is there a way of making it "fire and forget"? That is, make it so the method actually runs asynchronously via a Task and have it continue to the next line without 'await'ing? This way if the user wants to await it then they can, and those that want to just run it as a Task can do so.

Comment: They all work that way out of the box.  The user is never forced to await anything.  And if you only want it to be fire-and-forget, make the return type `void`.  But if you do return a `Task`, it's up to the user to await on it or not.  You don't need to do anything special to support both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Moving my comment to an answer, because I guess it is)

All async methods work that way out of the box. The user is never forced to await anything. It's up to the user to await on your async method or not. You don't need to do anything special to support both cases.

**Example:**

```
public async Task MyAsyncMethod() {
    // do something asynchronous in here...
}
```

You can call the method with `await`:

```
await obj.MyAsyncMethod();
```

... or not...

```
obj.MyAsyncMethod();
```

In this last case, the method will be a fire-and-forget.

The user can also choose to do the following with your method:

```
Task t = obj.MyAsyncMethod();

// perform some other tasks that don't depend on the completion of "MyAsyncMethod"

await t; // now I want to await on the task before continuing.

// perform more tasks that require the completion of "MyAsyncMethod"
```

And as you can see, I didn't need to make any changes to my async method to support all 3 cases.

Comment: +1 but I wouldn't recommend making code `void`. `void` `async` methods were *specifically* created for one, narrow, usage - event handlers. If you find them anywhere else, it's usually a bug. See e.g. [Avoid async void methods](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and related article linked from it

Comment: @Damien: You're right, it's probably best not to mention that option in this context.  Thanks.  Editing that out.

Comment: It's true that you're not forced to await; however, my understanding is if you do not await then whatever is the the async method you are calling will be excecuted synchronously until the next await is encountered.

Comment: @Anthony - you might also want to read [Asynchronous Programming in C# part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx) by Eric Lippert, which may clear up some of your confusion about what `async` and `await` *actually* mean.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think I have a decent grasp of what's going on behind the scenes, how the compiler builds a state machine underneath and how awaitables work. The problem (or maybe it's not a problem) I'm having is calling the async method without await and having some of its code running synchronously which means it's not *really* asynchronous after all. Then again, if it worked the way I would like it to then it would lead to a Task within a Task which I don't like either.

Comment: @Anthony: I see your point.  But usually, if designed correctly, the synchronous parts of your method (the parts before you hit an await) should not take long at all.  The expensive parts are that ones that would be awaited.  If this is not true, then the `async` method probably needs a `Task.Run()` or something similar inside it to make sure that it doesn't  run synchronously.

Comment: @Anthony The async method has no way of possibly knowing whether or not its awaited.  It can't conceivably behave differently when its awaited vs when it isn't.  The method will still be run asynchronously even if you aren't awaiting the returned task.  The only difference is that the method will never be able to look at the result of the asynchronous operation, see if it errored, or what the error was, or to reliably execute some code after that operation has finished.

Comment: @Anthony - then the only point of confusion there may be is if you're working in the context of a single-threaded synchronization context (i.e. the UI thread). In such a case, you don't, specifically, need the caller to be `await`ing to make progress, but you do need that caller (and every other piece of code) to not be running on that single-threaded context.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand that `await` does not execute the method. `await` only registers the continuation of the remaining function in the `Task` object that is returned by the function. (actually in the Awaiter of the `Task` object).

So the function is executing, no matter if and how you wait for it's completion. You can store the `Task` object and `await` it later. Or you wait for it blocking using the `Task.Wait` function.

Comment: Understood; however, my understanding is if you do not await then whatever is the the async method you are calling will be excecuted synchronously until the next await is encountered.

Comment: That is not absolutely correct. What is in the method is executed synchronously anyway until the first `await` inside the method. The first `await` in the method will the cause the function to return the `Task` object.

Comment: Right, it would run synchronous regardless but I was wondering if there was an alternative where we could 'package up' the entire async task as an actual Task that can be run asynchronously in its entirety.

Comment: There is! `Task.Run` has a overload that takes a function returning a `Task` that does exactly that.

Comment: @Anthony The method is going to synchronously start an asynchronous task.  it's not going to synchronously wait until that task finishes just because you don't `await` it.  Essentially all asynchronous methods synchronously set up an asynchronous operation (ideally very quickly) then return, then do work asynchronously.  You're doing all of those same things even without an `await`.  The method is still conceptually asynchronous.

Comment: oh my... Task.Run. I don't know why I forgot all about it. :( Thanks!